# ¿Cómo me refiero al registro al cual pertenece el botón DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

estoy trabajando con una tabla que me muestra los alumnos registrados en mi base de datos, he creado una función para obtener el detallado de la información del alumno y mostrarlo en una tabla, pero no logro que me recupere los datos del registro al cual pertenece el botón, esto es lo que he hecho:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   table = $('#alumnos').DataTable({
        "ajax":{
            "url": "consulta.php",
            "dataSrc":""
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data": "apellidos"},
            {"data": "nombres"},
            {"data": "cedula"},
            {"data": "name_group"},
            {"data": "name_sec"},

        ],
        "columnDefs": [ {
            "targets":5 ,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button  class='btn_detalles'>Editar</button>"
        } ],
      
       orderCellsTop: true,
       fixedHeader: true

    });
            obtener_data("#alumnos tbody", table);
    
    $('#alumnos thead tr').clone(true).appendTo( '#alumnos thead' );
    
    $('#alumnos thead tr:eq(1) th').each( function (i) {
        var title = $(this).text(); //es el nombre de la columna
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar por...'+title+'" />' );
        
        $( 'input', this ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
            if ( table.column(i).search() !== this.value ) {
                table
                .column(i)
                .search( this.value )
                .draw();
            }
        } );
    } ); 
});
```

y aquí la función que debería devolverme la información:

```
var obtener_data = function(tbody, table) {




$(tbody).bind('click', '.btn_detalles', function(){
         var data = table.row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();
         var cedu = $('#cedu').text( data.cedula);
         var cedu = $('#nombres_a').text( data.nombres);
         var cedu = $('#apellidos_a').text( data.apellidos);
         var cedu = $('#fechaNacimiento_A').text( data.F_N);
         var cedu = $('#sexo_a').text( data.sexo);
         var cedu = $('#na_a').text( data.Nacionalidad);
         var cedu = $('#pais_a').text( data.pais);
         if (data.tlf==="") {
            data.tlf = "N/A"
         }
         var Tlf = $('#tlf_a').text( data.tlf);
         if (data.correo_e==="") {
            data.correo_e = "N/A"
         }
         var Correo = $('#correo_a').text( data.correo_e);
         var cedu = $('#dir_a').text( data.direccion);
         var cedu = $('#grado_a').text( data.name_group);
         var cedu = $('#seccion_a').text( data.name_sec);
         var FechaI = $('#FechaI_a').text( data.F_I);
         var cedu = $('#rep_a').text( data.rep);

        
});
```

esto es lo que hice pero me devuelve que la variable tiene un valor indefinido, espero haberme explicado bien, gracias de ante mano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como los datos se cargan desde un json se debe agregar la opción `initComplete` al DataTable para que se ejecute la función `obtener_data()` cuando ya se haya renderizado la tabla.

```
initComplete: function() {
     obtener_data(table);
}
```

El código para agregar el evento clic es así:

```
$('.btn_detalles').bind('click', function(){
         var data = table.row( $(this).parents("tr") ).data();
         console.log(data);   
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#alumnos').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [{
                "data": "id"
            },
            {
                "data": "name"
            },
            {
                "data": "username"
            },
            {
                "data": "email"
            },
            {
                "data": "phone"
            },

        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": 5,
            "data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<button  class='btn_detalles'>Editar</button>"
        }],

        orderCellsTop: true,
        fixedHeader: true,
        initComplete: function() {
            obtener_data( table);
        }

    });


    $('#alumnos thead tr').clone(true).appendTo('#alumnos thead');

    $('#alumnos thead tr:eq(1) th').each(function(i) {
        var title = $(this).text(); //es el nombre de la columna
        $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Buscar por...' + title + '" />');

        $('input', this).on('keyup change', function() {
            if (table.column(i).search() !== this.value) {
                table
                    .column(i)
                    .search(this.value)
                    .draw();
            }
        });
    });
});

var obtener_data = function(table) {

    $('.btn_detalles').bind('click', function() {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="alumnos" class="display" style="width:100%">
       
</table>
```

Comment: no me funciono amigo, no se si será que yo no tengo los datos en la tabla sino que los importo desde la base de datos con json y agrego a la tabla mediante datatable al igual que el boton

Comment: Actualicé el ejemplo cargando datos desde un json.

Comment: al activarlo refiriéndome al tbody funciona pero al referirme al botón no hace nada

Comment: Sería mejor que actualices la pregunta y agregues el código completo del DataTable.

Comment: ya edite la pregunta hay esta todo lo que tengo hecho hasta ahora

Comment: Probaste con en el ejemplo que puse `$('.btn_detalles').bind('click', function(){`? Me parece que sigues teniendo el mismo error, no se le agrega el evento clic al botón.

Comment: si la probé, cuando me refiero al botón la función no hace nada

Comment: Ok, ya actualicé la respuesta.

Comment: si amigo, ya me funciono muchas gracias